# Is There a Way to Version an HTTP Cookie?

Tags: http, cookies

Is it possible to provide version information to go with an HTTP cookie?  I have a cookie which tells the page whether or not to prompt a user for action, based on whether or not the user wants the prompt.  On a version upgrade of the page, I need to prompt the user regardless.  Can I integrate this into my existing cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie is little more than a string with an expiry time. You can encode whatever information you like into that cookie, including a number representing a version.